# What can't Django decode my template?

Tags: django

I saved a Microsoft Word document as an HTML document. I then copied and pasted the generated HTML into a Django template "document.html".

I then mapped a URL to a simple view that loads this template.

```
def viewDocument(request):
    return render_to_response('document.html')
```

Afterwards, I get this error when access the page for that view.

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /viewDocument/
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 67600: invalid continuation byte
```

Strangely, the HTML in document.html displays fine when I open the page generated from Microsoft Word in Google Chrome on my laptop. How come it doesn't work as a Django template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the file isn't encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you, my template was encoded in MacRoman. Changing the encoding of my text editor to UTF-8 fixed this issue.

Comment: Stupid me and genius you ))